# C++: Cannot initialize enum value from a constant of the same type

Tags: c++, enums, initialization, constexpr, scoped-enums

For unknown reason I cannot initialize enum value from a `constexpr` value. Here is my code:

```
enum class Enum: unsigned int; //Forward declaration

constexpr Enum constant = static_cast<Enum>(2);

enum class Enum: unsigned int {
  A = 0,
  B = 1,
  C = B,                                   //This works
  D = constant,                            //This FAILS
  E = static_cast<unsigned int>(constant), //This works
  F = Enum::B                              //This works
};
```

What I cannot understand is why I can write `C = B`, but cannot write `D = constant` (`B` and `constant` have the same type!)

I still can do `E = static_cast<unsigned int>(constant)`, but it is too verbose (in my real-life code each enum value is initialized by a `constexpr` function call, and it is hard to put `static_cast<unsigned int>` everywhere).

Comment: `B` and `constant` **do not** have the same type! `B` is an `unsigned int` but `constant` is an `Enum`.

Comment: But your code compiles without warning with MSVC but clang-cl gives an error about no implicit conversion from `Enum` to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Bathsheba basically any compiler other than MSVC fails: https://godbolt.org/z/7K5W3o

Comment: @AdrianMole I tried `unsigned int test = Enum::B;` after the `Enum`, and it cannot be compiled since `Enum::B` has `Enum` type.

Comment: But that is *outside* its class definition. *Inside* the class, it has the underlying type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

> C++: Cannot initialize enum value from a constant of the same type

First of all, the *enum type* and its *underlying type* are not the same, and the *enumerator* of the former shall be defined with, if any, a constexpr value of the underlying type or a constant expression *implicitly convertible* to the underlying type.

As covered in the non-normative example of [[dcl.enum]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.enum#10), there are no implicit conversions between *a scoped* enum and an integer, not even to its explicitly specified fixed underlying type:

> The value of an enumerator or an object **of an unscoped enumeration type** is converted to an integer by integral promotion. [ *Example:* [...]
>
> Note that this implicit enum to int conversion is not provided for a scoped enumeration:
>
> ```
> enum class Col { red, yellow, green };
> int x = Col::red;               // error: no Col to int conversion
> Col y = Col::red;
> if (y) { }                      // error: no Col to bool conversion
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

and, as governed by the non-presence of scoped enumerations in the normative text of [[conv.integral]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.integral#1) and [[conv.prom]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.prom#4) ([[conv.prom]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.prom#3) for unscoped enumerations types whose underlying type is not fixed) [**emphasis** mine]:

> **[conv.integral]/1**
>
> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. A prvalue of **an unscoped enumeration** type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>
> **[conv.prom]/4**
>
> A prvalue of **an unscoped enumeration** type whose underlying type is fixed ([dcl.enum]) **can be converted to a prvalue of its underlying type**. Moreover, if integral promotion can be applied to its underlying type, a prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is fixed can also be converted to a prvalue of the promoted underlying type.

As such, your program, particularly the enumeration definition `D = constant`, is ill-formed.

And indeed, if we modify your example such that `Enum` is changed into a non-scoped enumeration, the program is no longer ill-formed.

```
enum Enum: unsigned int; //Forward declaration

constexpr Enum constant = static_cast<Enum>(2);

enum Enum: unsigned int {
  A = 0,
  B = 1,
  C = B,                                  // Ok
  D = constant,                           // Ok, implicit conversion
  E = static_cast<unsigned int>(constant) // Ok
};

int main() { }
```

---

> Then why `C = B` in my code works?

Because of the somewhat tricky clause [[dcl.enum]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.enum#5), which states that

> **Following the closing brace** of an enum-specifier, **each enumerator has the type of its enumeration**. If the underlying type is fixed, the type of each enumerator **prior to the closing brace is the underlying type** [...]. If the underlying type **is not fixed**, **the type of each enumerator prior to the closing brace** is determined as follows:
>
> - [...]

In layman terms, the type of each enumerator basically changes depending on whether its viewed from within the definition of the enumeration or from outside of it.

This means that inside of the enum definition, we may use a previously defined enumerator in the definition of one that follows, as they both have the type (ignoring some details in [[dcl.enum]/5.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.enum#5.1) and [[dcl.enum]/5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.enum#5.3) for enumerations where the underlying type is not fixed), no matter is the enum is scoped or not (i.e., no need for implicit conversions), whereas outside of the definition of the enum, these enumerators have the same type as that of the enum itself.

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class Enum: unsigned int; //Forward declaration

constexpr Enum constant = static_cast<Enum>(0);

// Forward a constexpr value whilst asserting
// type identity between two type template parameters.
template<typename T, typename U, unsigned int VALUE>
struct assert_and_get_value {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, U>, "");
    static constexpr unsigned int value = VALUE;  
};

enum class Enum: unsigned int {
  A = 1,
  B,

  // C and B here are both of type 'unsigned int'
  C = B,
  D = assert_and_get_value<decltype(C), unsigned int, 5>::value,

  // Note that 'constant', however, in this scope, has type 'Enum'.
  E = assert_and_get_value<decltype(constant), const Enum, 6>::value,
};

// At this point, however, the type of each enumerator
// is the type of the enum.
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(Enum::A), Enum>, "");
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(Enum::A), unsigned int>, "");

int main() {}
```

Comment: Because of the somewhat tricky clause [\[dcl.enum\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.enum#5), which states that _"Following the closing brace of an enum-specifier, each enumerator has the type of its enumeration"_ and _"If the underlying type is fixed, the type of each enumerator prior to the closing brace is the underlying type ..."_. Basically the type of the enumerator "changes" with the scope, and within the definition of your enum (if the underlying type is fixed, as in your example), the type of the enumerators are that of the underlying type, not that of the enum.

Comment: OMG! That is what I was actually asking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include this tricky clause.

Comment: @AntonSukhinov Happy to help. I've added an expanded version of my comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems logical to me.

There are two kinds of entities here.

1. Class being enum
2. its internal type

B and C are both of the second kind so you can assign one to another.
On the other hand D is of second kind and *constant* is of the first one. And *enum class* concept was designed to prevent implicit conversion from enum to its underlying type, thus your compilation error.